# HTML form variable for execution

Tags: html, forms

i have a HTML form which takes any linux command as an input and I want to execute that command on the server and provide output back to the user. My issue is I am not able to pass the command entered in the textbox to Linux using execCode function. Following is my code.

Please advise how can i get this thing working.
Thanks.

```
<form name="runCommand" method="GET">
  iDirect Command Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="command" >
  <!--input type="text" -->
  <br><br>
  var = document.getElementById("command").value
  <!--input type="submit" value="Run Command" onclick="execCode('echo document.getElementById("command").value');return false"-->
  <input type="submit" value="Run Command" onclick="execCode('echo var');return false">
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually you are not running the command on the server, but it is running on  the client. You need a server side language to process instruction on the server.

Comment: @Danibix That's right.  An `action` attribute in the form element could be the name of the php file to take the `command` input and `exec()` it on the server.  This is, of course, a terrible idea.  Don't put this website in front of any user you don't trust.

Comment: I do not think that is the case. Because if i pass 'pwd' or 'ls' or any other command it works well int the system. By the way this webpage is going to run only on server so same machine is server and client. The problem I am running into is I am not able to evaluate the variable in execCode function. If you know how to do that please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you forgot to add an id attribute to the input named command

2) you should use a name after var, ex: var command = document.getElementById("command").value

3) execCode('echo var') will always send the command 'echo var' to the server, to send the value of the command, you should use execCode('echo ' + command)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I corrected the coding issues and tried with execCode('echo '+ var) but it doesn't really gets the value of var in that case. Where can I learn about execCode function itself? Would you know? I am using an existing framework so I don't know which technologies they are using in it. Any help would be great.

Comment: Sorry, i meant execCode('echo '+ command) in my example. You use var to create a new variable, but you need to name it and use it's name to use it. What is the name of the framework you use?

Comment: You are correct. My system had some issue (still has an issue). execCode('whatever '+ <variable_name>) is the way to get variable value.  Thanks.